# fortran coarray image access not working properly?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran-coarrays

Working with a simple gfortran coarray program.

For some reason accessing images of a variable from the root process (e.g. a[2]) doesn't work.

Am I accessing these images correctly? Is it possible I have compiled the coarray library incorrectly?

**coarray.f90**

```
program coarraytest
    implicit none
    integer, codimension[*]:: a
    integer:: tot
    if(this_image()==1) then
     a=10
    endif
    if(this_image()==2) then
     a=20
    endif
    sync all                    ! synchronize
    if(this_image()==1) then
    tot=a+a[2]
     print *, a, a[2], tot
    end if
sync all
print *, this_image(), ': ', a
end program
```

**Output**

```
  10           0   682453724
   1 :           10
   2 :           20
```

**Notes**

system:

Ubuntu Linux 20.04

gfortran

OpenMPI (OpenRTE) 4.0.3

Compilation:

```
caf coarray.f90 -o coarray.o
```

Execution:

```
cafrun -n 2 coarraytest.o
```

Comment: Works for me (Linux Mint 19 Tara, gfortran 7.4, OpenMPI 2.1.1-8). What are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04,gfortran, mpiexec (OpenRTE) 4.0.3, edited into original post....So I wonder if the instillation went wrong

Comment: In general, it is not a good idea to hardcode the image indices (like 2 in your code). What if you intend to run this code on a single process? Here is an example error message with hard coded image index: `forrtl: severe (772): Image number 2 is not a valid image number; valid numbers are 1 to 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like it was a band install.
I followed this link first:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277932/cannot-install-open-coarrays-bin-for-gfortran-on-ubuntu-20-04

Which is outdated. Had to uninstall all that junk and follow the following link:

https://github.com/sourceryinstitute/OpenCoarrays/blob/master/INSTALL.md#linux